# 404 page not working for nested routes in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a notes app in React and I've built a 404 page and now if I go to a route that doesn't exist it shows a 404 page
for example, if I go to the route `/get-the-note/` I get a 404 page.
But the problem is that I have a route:

`<Route exact path="/single-note/:id" component={Singlenote}></Route>`

which needs an id and if I put the correct id like I have a note with id no `2` and if I go to the route `/single-note/2` it works but if I put an id that doesn't exist like if I put an id `120` which doesn't exist and I go to the route `/single-note/120` I get a plain page instead of a 404 page. I want it show the 404 page even if the id is incorrect

here is my app.js file:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./components/homepage.component";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Singlenote from "./components/singlenote.component";
import PageNotFound from "./components/404_page";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route exact path="/single-note/:id" component={Singlenote}></Route>
            <Route path="*"><PageNotFound /></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my 404 page:

```js
import React from 'react'

const PageNotFound = () => {
    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qIufhof.png" />
            <div id="info">
                <h3>This page could not be found</h3>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default PageNotFound
```

Answer (score 1):

The router has no way of knowing which IDs do and do not exist.

It's up to your `Singlenote` to render 404 content if there is no such ID.

For the last route in the Switch, you don't need the path at all, by the way.

```
<Route component={PageNotFound} />
```

Comment: so how can i get the router to know if the id exist or not

Answer (score 0):

The approach I suggest for this is by modifying your `Singlenote` component, with a `useEffect` hook, that checks if the id provided exists or not, only once on mount (`useEffect(() => { code for check }, []);`). In the event that the id does not exist, you can redirect the execution to your 404 component, by using history (e.g. `history.push('*')`, where * is used as the path to redirect to, you could use something else that is not covered in the routes, so it will go to 404).

I have to add that this is not a good approach, I would personally go with a notification or other indicator displayed when accessing your `Singlenote` component with an id that does not exist (again with useEffect), which informs the user that no results or data were found for the given id.